# Google Custom Search via API is too slow

Tags: google-custom-search, query-performance

I am using Google Custom Search to index content on my website.

When I use a REST client to make the get request at

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=xxx&q=query&cx=xx

I get response in sub seconds.

But when I try to make the call using my code, it takes up six seconds. What am I doing wrong ?

```
__author__ = 'xxxx'

import urllib2
import logging
import gzip

from cfc.apikey.googleapi import get_api_key
from cfc.url.processor import set_query_parameter
from StringIO import StringIO


CX = 'xxx:xxx'

URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=%s&cx=%s&q=sd&fields=kind,items(title)" % (get_api_key(), CX)


def get_results(query):
    url = set_query_parameter(URL, 'q', query)
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
    request.add_header('User-Agent','cfc xxxx (gzip)')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
        buf = StringIO(response.read())
        f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
        data = f.read()
        return data
```

I have implemented performance tips mentioned in [Performance Tips](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/performance). I would appreciate any help. Thanks.